# displaying summary based on user choices

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using tab control with tab pages to get user input. In last before prining I have to show the user summary that is going to be printed.

Based on input there can be 2 sets of data to display. One will be replaced at a time.

I am a newbie in WinForm but in Asp.net there is a control panel, kindly gudie me is there a control that I can use for this kind of display.

I thought to use panel or groupbox but I am not aware of how to manage there location and display. I tried putting these on each other and on click try to bring requried one on front, make it visible and hide other but it does not work properly. Any advice please, HERE IS MY CODE:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        groupBox2.Visible = false;
        groupBox1.BringToFront();


        groupBox1.Visible = true;

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox1.Visible = false;
        groupBox2.BringToFront();

        groupBox2.Visible = true ;
    }
```

**EDIT**
I have noted the issue is when I put both group boxes on each other top one becomes a part of other. If I try to do this by panels I also have to manage all controls individually. Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally use report viewer to show selection because later I was going to print repots as well

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

Create two UserControls containing the controls you need in your situation and add a GroupBox to your Form. Do not add your UserControls to your Form.

Add two instance variable for your UserControls to the Form, and initialize them in the FormLoad event (you could for instance add one of the controls to the GroupBox with the designer, copy and paste the initialization code from InitializeComponent to Form_Load, remove the control and then do the same for the other control). Be careful to avoid to add the UserControls to the Control collection of the GroupBox.

Finally, when you know what to display (or have to switch between your visualization), simply clear the Control collection of the GroupBox and add the UserControl you want.

The following code gives you a sample using two Labels instead of your real UserControls.

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private bool sel1 = true; 
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(31, 44);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "One";
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(31, 44);
        this.label2.Name = "label1";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 13);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label2.Text = "Two";
        groupBox1.Controls.Add(label1);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox1.Controls.Clear();
        sel1 = !sel1;
        if (sel1)
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(label1);
        else
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(label2);
    }
```